# Allow user to update view content once, for every page the view is on?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

New to MVC and Umbraco, but chugging along.

One issue I have is I have a view that at present just displays some images & text (sprinkled with some CSS). Now this view is found on a number of pages, and having the ability to update it in one place, which then changes all the pages the view is included is great.

But I'd like to be able allow the user to update some simple text / images on this view. Usually I'd go and create some properties on the document type, which the user can edit in the content section. But Is there anyway I can do this without having to create the same properties on each page this view is on? As this means the user has to update this view on every page its present, which means it completely loses the benefit of being a view!

Perhaps I just don't understand Umbraco that well yet.

I'm asking if I can allow a user to update the view ONCE in Umbraco, and those changes filter through to all the pages the view is on. Without creating properties for each page.

I can supply code, but this is more of a logic question, I don't have a problem with the code as such.

Hit me back if you need any more information.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

The content like logo, copyrights which appear on all the pages, you can add those properties to the document type of Home page, in the master page, you can easily get the home page and fetch those properties to show them. You change it in home page, and it reflects everywhere.

If there's a scenario like content is not for all pages but only some pages like there is a list and details pages for each item, then you can assign the properties to the document type of list page and from template of details page you can get the parent node of content and show it there. You will have to update it only in list page content.

It all depends on your design of your site how you want to manage it.